# How do they locate the physical body in Animatrix: Kid's story?

Tags: the-matrix-revolutions, the-matrix-reloaded, the-animatrix

This is regarding a short story from the [Animatrix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0328832/) by the name **Kid's Story**

The story is about the Kid that Neo helps "free" himself from the Matrix. This is the same kid who is shown in the Reloaded and Revolutions movies.
In the Animatrix, the kid falls of a building and dies in the Matrix. However, he wakes up in the real world. Neo an Trinity are there when the kid wakes up. The theme here is - self substantiation, being able to exit the Matrix without external help.

The "kid" is not given any tracer pill, how do Neo and Trinity end up finding the physical body of the kid among all of those pods? Is there any suggestion in the extra materials as to how they located the kid's body?

Comment: Asked and answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28061/animatrix-in-kids-story-how-was-the-kid-found) on scifi:SE

Answer (score 2):

Echoing [Trenin's excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28061/animatrix-in-kids-story-how-was-the-kid-found) (to the same question on Scifi:SE), the simplest answer is that they were already very close to the Kid's location. When they saw him "self-substantiate", this presumably had much the same effect on his "input/output carrier signal" as taking the red pill, allowing them to rescue him before he drowned:

> *They were watching the kid in much the same way that Morpheus and
>   company watched Neo in the first movie. In the Kid's story, Neo calls
>   him, and in an scene reminiscent to the movie, tells him to get out of
>   the classroom now. The kid is chased by agents to the roof, and
>   eventually jumps off.*
>
> *The kid presumably "wakes up" from the matrix and is disposed of the
>   same way Neo was.*
>
> *Recall that in the first movie, the red pill tracer program was taken
>   by Neo and then he is woken up less than 5 minutes later. So the ship
>   had to have been close enough to Neo's location in the physical world
>   to get to him relatively quickly. Perhaps the same was true for the
>   kid. They knew something was going to go down (Neo called the kid to
>   warn him) and when they saw him "self substantiate" (the first ever to
>   do so) they reacted quickly and made it to the pools in time to
>   recover him.*